# What is the best e-Ink device for academic paper reading and hand annotation?

Tags: literature-review, reading

Having just started my PhD, my academic paper reading and review has ramped up dramatically and so far I've tried the two predominant methods of doing so: on a laptop or with physically printed papers. I soon found both methods to have their respective pros and cons:

1. **Laptop reading** allows for highlighting and text annotations, which I can always easily return back to on different devices (e.g. by annotating the papers in Mendeley and syncing the Mendeley app across all my devices) without the need to maintain a physical copy of the paper I originally annotated. On the major downside, the eye-strain is significant to the point that I have to take regular breaks and consequently struggle to maintain focus.
2. **Physical copies** do away with the eye-strain and are more comfortable to annotate by hand (relative to using the mouse for highlighting and keyboard for added notes) but present organizational (*Now where did I put that paper I marked with an important insight...?*) and traveling challenges (I travel a lot and carrying a stack of papers with me is becoming less and less feasible).

Therefore I decided it is time to try and find a tablet/e-reader solution which incorporates the best of both worlds. Specifically, I would sort the features from most to least important as follows:

1. Eye-friendly reading experience supporting paper and textbook PDFs,
2. with low-latency writing for easy and natural highlighting and hand-written notes directly on the paper PDFs,
3. long-term and regular software support and
4. a device which would double as a classic e-reader for leisure-time reading, such as a Kindle (if I already have a PDF reader, why not also have an e-book reader in one device).

The first point brought me within the e-Ink device sphere and two major contenders cropped up: the reMarkable 2 and the Onyx Boox Note Air. However it seems pretty difficult to decide between the two; specifically:

1. **reMarkable 2**: while reportedly boasting very low latency and a great writing experience, several reviews have pointed out it becomes very laggy with large PDF files (so I am not certain if it can handle textbooks or even very long, ~30-page articles with plenty of figures), saves very large annotated PDFs (since apparently all the hand-annotations are saved as an added image layer on top of the original PDF), requires regular pen-tip replacements (which could get pricey on the long run) and is reportedly very limited as an e-reader.
2. **Onyx Boox Note Air**: while again reportedly having a low latency, containing powerful hardware (which should deal nicely with large files), and serving as an excellent e-Book reader (thanks to its Android OS which supports a variety of Google store apps), the writing feeling is supposed to be much poorer (like writing on glass, which I wonder how I would get used to) as well as serving as a full tablet - most people would consider this a perk, however I am quite happy with the narrow focus of the reMarkable; I am not looking for a standard tablet and believe all the added features (music, video, email, etc..) are not only redundant, but could also prove distracting.

Does anyone have any experience using the above two devices (or perhaps any other, better ones) for the purposes described above? Would such e-Ink devices even be a good long-term investment, or is the technology still in its infancy (meaning that the technological advancement could make these quite pricey devices obsolete in a couple year's time)?